# PHP; auto generate year according to registration date

Tags: php, wordpress, date, fixed

I'm using s2member with WordPress.

I set up a Fixed EOT(End of Term) for July 31st.

Here's the coding I'm using..

```
<?php
$now = strtotime("now");
$fixed_time = strtotime("31 July 2013");
$days_until_fixed_time = round(($fixed_time - $now) / ($seconds_in_one_day = $86400));
?>

[s2member-Pro-PayPal-Form... tp="<?php echo $days_until_fixed_time; ?>" tt="D" ... /]
```

The code works fine as it is to set the EOT date as July 31, 2013.

But I need the year to auto generate according to the date.

If the user registers **before** July 31, EOT year should stay the current year.

If the user registers **after** July 31, EOT year should be set to the following year(2014).

*And this will work without having to modify every year.*

Hope this makes sense! Thank you for your help!

**EDITED**

would this work...

```
<?php
$now = strtotime("now");
$fixed_time = strtotime("31 July " . date("Y"));

if($now > $fixed_time)
$fixed_time = strtotime("+1 year", $fixed_time);

$days_until_fixed_time = round(($fixed_time - $now) / ($seconds_in_one_day = $86400));
?>

[s2member-Pro-PayPal-Form... tp="<?php echo $days_until_fixed_time; ?>" tt="D" ... /]
```

**EDIT #2**
have this code now..

```
<?php
$now = strtotime("now");
$mmdd = (int)date("M d");
$yyyy = (int)date("Y");
if ($mmdd <= 731)
$fixed_time = strtotime("31 July " . $yyyy);
else
$fixed_time = strtotime("31 July " . ($yyyy+1));

$days_until_fixed_time = round(($fixed_time - $now) / ($seconds_in_one_day = "86400"));

[s2member-Pro-PayPal-Form... tp="<?php echo $days_until_fixed_time; ?>" tt="D" ... /]
?>
```

problem is...

a) **FIXED** <strike>the EOT date comes out to be July 30th.</strike>

b) if the user registers AFTER the date, i get an error on the page saying the value needs to be 1 or greater..

*"Invalid form configuration. Invalid "tp" attribute. The Trial Period. When provided, must be >= 1."*

still need help..


**=============== SOLUTION ================**

Figured out a working model! Thanks for everybody's help!

```
<?php
$now = strtotime("now");
$fixed_time = strtotime("31 July " . date("Y"));

if($now > $fixed_time)
    $fixed_time = strtotime("+1 year", $fixed_time);

$days_until_fixed_time = round(($fixed_time - $now) / (86400));
?>

[s2member-Pro-PayPal-Form... tp="<?php echo $days_until_fixed_time; ?>" tt="D" ... /]
```

This structure successfully implements July 31st as the EOT date. When the user registers before July 31st, the current year is set. If the user registers after July 31st, the next year is set.

Comment: $now would be when the user registers, yes. no matter when they register, the end term is July 31. it just depends if it's before or after July 31 so the system knows when to set the 'year'.

Comment: new changes look fine to me..

Comment: the EDITED code doesn't work. nothing shows up, doesn't display the PayPal form. Any ideas what could be wrong with it?

Comment: issue with EDITED code was the 'seconds_in_one_day'..fixed it but still had the same problem that I'm currently having with the latest update.

Comment: A seperate question is how you are displaying this. I'm not a wordpress expert but I don't think that the tags like [s2member-Pro-From..] works outside of the wordpress pages. So if you trying to display that as HTMl, i doubt it would work. That is just speculation since I don't know wordpress that well

Comment: @immulatin, that s2member pro tag generates the membership registration form. the value for 'tp' i believe is number of days til EOT date.

Comment: fixed problem 'a'...just need to fix problem 'b'..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just advance the year if we are after the `$fixed_time`

```
if($now > $fixed_time)
    $fixed_time = strtotime("+1 year", $fixed_time);
```

*UPDATE for new code:*

```
$now = strtotime("now");
$mmdd = (int)date("M d");
echo "mmdd is: $mmdd" . PHP_EOL;
```

Outputs:

> mmdd is: 0

That code does not work as intended. Casting a date to an int is a bad idea as you can see if produces 0, which means your if statement will ALWAYS be true;

My suggestion works fine look at this code that tests before the cutoff and after the cutoff. Your code is in the doStuff function with the `strtotime("now")` commented out so I can change the date strings:

```
echo "Checking for before cutoff date: " . PHP_EOL;
doStuff("30 July 2013"); // Before the cutoff
echo PHP_EOL . "Checking for after cutoff: " . PHP_EOL;
doStuff("1 August 2013"); // After the cutoff

function doStuff($datestr){
    $now = strtotime($datestr);
    //$now = strtotime("now");
    $fixed_time = strtotime("31 July " . date("Y"));

    echo "Fixed time before change is: " . date("m-d-Y", $fixed_time) . PHP_EOL;
    if($now > $fixed_time)
        $fixed_time = strtotime("+1 year", $fixed_time);

    echo "Fixed time is: " . date("m-d-Y", $fixed_time) . PHP_EOL;

    $days_until_fixed_time = round(($fixed_time - $now) / (86400));

    echo "Days until: $days_until_fixed_time" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
Checking for before cutoff date: 
    Fixed time before change is: 07-31-2013
    Fixed time is: 07-31-2013
    Days until: 1

Checking for after cutoff: 
    Fixed time before change is: 07-31-2013
    Fixed time is: 07-31-2014
    Days until: 364
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change this line to read the year dynamically:

```
$mmdd = (int)date("M d");
$yyyy = (int)date("Y");
if ($mmdd <= 731)
  $fixed_time = strtotime("31 July " . $yyyy);
else
  $fixed_time = strtotime("31 July " . ($yyyy+1));
```

that should work.

Comment: This works for BEFORE July 31st registered users but, if the user registers AFTER July 31...wouldn't that still set the date to the current year, not the next year?

Comment: Ah sorry didn't catch that. Edited the answer based on the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've converted $now into time() format:

```
$now = time();
$term = mktime(0,0,0,7,31);
$term = ( $now > $term ) ? $term + 31536000 : $term;
```

31536000 = number of seconds in 1 year

if you're doing this function a lot (in a loop?) strtotime is expensive

Comment: what do you mean 'in a loop'? this function is only called when a user registers for a membership.

Comment: At the end of the day, only use strtotime when you need it as it is more expensive than just adding two numbers together.

Comment: does it matter or make that much of a difference if it is only being used when a user clicks a button to submit a registration form? (only 100-200 times a year..)

Comment: No. I noticed a huge difference doing large iterations which is why I brought it up, but once in a call won't make much difference.